# dotnet slow build time, using monogame

Tags: c#, .net, performance, build, monogame

new to monogame. It seems like the build times are really slow for simple stuff. for example this very small window with a couple of sprites and a sound file take 9 seconds. this adds up when i'm tweaking, building, tweaking, building.

is there a way to speed up build times, or make them incremental? or maybe theres a different approach?

```
dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0-preview-21378-03+d592862ed for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  You are using a preview version of .NET. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  D:/.../snd_music.wma
  D:/.../spr_background.jpg
  D:/.../spr_lives.png
  testGame -> D:\...\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\testGame.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:08.45
```

```
Target Performance Summary:

        1 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk            1 calls
        1 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                         1 calls
        1 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                    1 calls
        1 ms  CollectPackageDownloads                    1 calls
        1 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectSpec                1 calls
        1 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    1 calls
        1 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromTransitiveProjectReferences   1 calls
        1 ms  _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties   1 calls
        1 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
        1 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathItemsPerFramework   1 calls
        1 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedAppHostUsage           1 calls
        1 ms  _CheckForNETCoreSdkIsPreview               1 calls
        1 ms  ResolveLockFileReferences                  1 calls
        1 ms  _GenerateDotnetCliToolReferenceSpecs       1 calls
        1 ms  AddWindowsSdkKnownFrameworkReferences      2 calls
        2 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                     1 calls
        2 ms  _ComputeUserRuntimeAssemblies              1 calls
        2 ms  _CollectTargetFrameworkForTelemetry        2 calls
        2 ms  GenerateNETCompatibleDefineConstants       1 calls
        2 ms  _GenerateCompileDependencyCache            1 calls
        2 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromThisProject   1 calls
        2 ms  CreateManifestResourceNames                1 calls
        2 ms  AssignTargetPaths                          1 calls
        2 ms  IncrementalClean                           1 calls
        2 ms  ApplyImplicitVersions                      2 calls
        2 ms  _GetRestoreTargetFrameworksOutput          1 calls
        2 ms  CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo                   1 calls
        2 ms  _ComputeReferenceAssemblies                1 calls
        3 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   2 calls
        3 ms  CreateGeneratedAssemblyInfoInputsCacheFile   1 calls
        3 ms  ResolveFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
        4 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    1 calls
        4 ms  PrepareForBuild                            1 calls
        4 ms  _GenerateProjectRestoreGraphPerFramework   1 calls
        4 ms  IncludeContent                             4 calls
        6 ms  _HandlePackageFileConflicts                1 calls
        6 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileCore        1 calls
        6 ms  _GetRestoreProjectStyle                    2 calls
        7 ms  PrepareContentBuilder                      1 calls
        7 ms  ResolveTargetingPackAssets                 1 calls
        8 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites         1 calls
        9 ms  _GetAllRestoreProjectPathItems             1 calls
        9 ms  UpdateAspNetToFrameworkReference           2 calls
       13 ms  _GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFilesInputCache   1 calls
       15 ms  _LoadRestoreGraphEntryPoints               1 calls
       15 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              1 calls
       16 ms  _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal                  1 calls
       18 ms  CollectContentReferences                   1 calls
       24 ms  FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences       1 calls
       31 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                 1 calls
       40 ms  _GetRestoreSettings                        1 calls
       84 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   1 calls
       88 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                       1 calls
      103 ms  GenerateBuildDependencyFile                1 calls
      109 ms  GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles     1 calls
      129 ms  _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory   1 calls
      158 ms  ProcessFrameworkReferences                 2 calls
      158 ms  _FilterRestoreGraphProjectInputItems       1 calls
      170 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  1 calls
      171 ms  _CreateAppHost                             1 calls
      193 ms  CoreCompile                                1 calls
      231 ms  _GenerateRestoreGraph                      1 calls
      335 ms  Restore                                    1 calls
     7016 ms  RunContentBuilder                          1 calls

Task Performance Summary:
        0 ms  ValidateExecutableReferences               1 calls
        0 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                         1 calls
        0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          1 calls
        1 ms  ResolveFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
        1 ms  GetRestoreFrameworkReferencesTask          1 calls
        1 ms  Delete                                     1 calls
        1 ms  GetRestoreProjectReferencesTask            1 calls
        1 ms  Message                                    6 calls
        1 ms  CheckForDuplicateFrameworkReferences       2 calls
        1 ms  GetRestorePackageDownloadsTask             1 calls
        1 ms  JoinItems                                  1 calls
        1 ms  GetRestorePackageReferencesTask            1 calls
        1 ms  CreateWindowsSdkKnownFrameworkReferences   2 calls
        1 ms  ShowPreviewMessage                         1 calls
        1 ms  GetRestoreDotnetCliToolsTask               1 calls
        1 ms  AllowEmptyTelemetry                        2 calls
        1 ms  CreateCSharpManifestResourceName           1 calls
        1 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                     3 calls
        1 ms  AssignTargetPath                           7 calls
        1 ms  ApplyImplicitVersions                      2 calls
        1 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          1 calls
        1 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      3 calls
        2 ms  AssignCulture                              2 calls
        2 ms  CreateItem                                 4 calls
        2 ms  Hash                                       3 calls
        2 ms  GetProjectTargetFrameworksTask             1 calls
        2 ms  GetPackageDirectory                        8 calls
        2 ms  NuGetMessageTask                           1 calls
        2 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   2 calls
        2 ms  CheckIfPackageReferenceShouldBeFrameworkReference   4 calls
        2 ms  FindUnderPath                              5 calls
        3 ms  GetRestoreProjectStyleTask                 2 calls
        3 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig                1 calls
        5 ms  ResolvePackageFileConflicts                1 calls
        6 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           7 calls
        6 ms  CallTarget                                 2 calls
        7 ms  ResolveTargetingPackAssets                 1 calls
        7 ms  WarnForInvalidProjectsTask                 1 calls
        9 ms  MakeDir                                    3 calls
       14 ms  WriteLinesToFile                           3 calls
       36 ms  ResolveAppHosts                            2 calls
       39 ms  GetRestoreSettingsTask                     1 calls
       87 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                       1 calls
      101 ms  GenerateDepsFile                           1 calls
      107 ms  GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles          1 calls
      117 ms  ProcessFrameworkReferences                 2 calls
      169 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
      170 ms  Copy                                       4 calls
      170 ms  CreateAppHost                              1 calls
      180 ms  Csc                                        1 calls
      327 ms  RestoreTask                                1 calls
      349 ms  MSBuild                                    7 calls
     7014 ms  Exec                                       1 calls
```

Content:
[image: 3 files, 5megabytes]

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace testGame
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var game = new Game1())
                game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Game1.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace testGame
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
        private Texture2D _balloon, _background;
        private Color _pulsing;
        private Vector2 _ballonPos;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            _balloon = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_lives");
            _background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_background");

            MediaPlayer.Play(Content.Load<Song>("snd_music"));

        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();
            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            base.Update(gameTime);
            int redComponent = gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds / 4;
            _pulsing = new Color(redComponent, 0, 0);

            _ballonPos = Vector2.Zero;
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
            _spriteBatch.Begin();
            _spriteBatch.Draw(_background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

            _spriteBatch.Draw(_balloon, _ballonPos, _pulsing);
            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

testGame.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
    <TieredCompilation>false</TieredCompilation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <ApplicationIcon>Icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Icon.ico" />
    <None Remove="Icon.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Icon.ico" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Icon.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MonoGameContentReference Include="Content\Content.mgcb" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentTypeReader" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Framework.DesktopGL" Version="3.8.0.1641" />
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task" Version="3.8.0.1641" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

app.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="testGame"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
           is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
           automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/pm</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">permonitorv2,permonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>

</assembly>
```

Comment: I saw you asked the same question on the r/MonoGame subreddit, and got several suggestions. If you find something that works for you, let us know over here in case it helps other people.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, Content Builder pipeline was the problem.  For whatever reason it sometimes skips already built content and other times rebuilds it.  Tried a few things but couldn't fix it.

I wasn't able to solve the problem, but instead changed my workflow.
Based on advice on r/MonoGame I ended up switching to Visual Studio and learning how to work via the "edit and continue" debugging workflow.  VSCode doesn't have this yet, which was why I had to switch.

Lo and behold, Visual Studio 2019 has this hot reloading feature called "Apply Code Changes" which makes working in C# kinda like working with Javascript (in a good way).  It lets me edit and design the program while it's still running in debug mode.  The only limitation I've hit so for is that it has to rebuild if I change the name of symbol.

[image]

Others suggested using Nez since it solves the pipeline issue and has good stuff built-in too.